# Help with problem using mail in ruby

Tags: ruby, email, smtp

The error that I get is:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for you@test.lindsaar.net
```

I am using mail-2.3.0
With Ruby 1.9
on windows XP.

The exact code I used is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mail'
Mail.deliver do
 from    'me@test.lindsaar.net'
 to      'you@test.lindsaar.net'
 subject 'Here is the image you wanted'
end
```

I don't understand what I am missing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message comes from your SMTP server. Although this message can have many causes, it is most likely you forgot to provide the necessary authentication data to your SMTP server.

Taken from http://www.eudora.com/techsupport/kb/1593hq.html:

> Most Internet Service Providers restrict access to their outgoing mail
>   servers to prevent SPAM from being sent through their mail servers. If
>   you are getting the "550 Relay Denied" error message, the outgoing
>   mail server cannot verify who you are and will not allow you to send
>   mail.

To configure `Mail` you have to prepare your own SMTP connection. See https://github.com/mikel/mail/wiki/Sending-email-via-google-smtp for an example.

You can get your username/password from your ISP (the one providing the SMTP server)

Comment: @DR Is this the same if I am not using rails? how can I find out what my server requires as a login and authentication?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read the tags carefully enough. The above example is Rails-specific. (removed)